# Creating different sections of people inside div

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Peoples</h1>
    <div class="people">
        <h1>John</h1>
        <img src="https://imgur.com/a/n8JDD" alt="p1">
        <p>Months on ye at by esteem desire warmth former. Sure that that way gave any fond now. His boy middleton sir nor engrossed affection excellent. Dissimilar compliment cultivated preference eat sufficient may. Well next door soon we mr he four. Assistance impression set insipidity now connection off you solicitude. Under as seems we me stuff those style at. Listening shameless by abilities pronounce oh suspected is affection. Next it draw in draw much bred. </p>
        <div class="link">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="people">
        <h1>Jonathan</h1>
        <img src="https://imgur.com/a/ovWud" alt="p2">
        <p>His followed carriage proposal entrance directly had elegance. Greater for cottage gay parties natural. Remaining he furniture on he discourse suspected perpetual. Power dried her taken place day ought the. Four and our ham west miss. Education shameless who middleton agreement how. We in found world chief is at means weeks smile.</p>
        <div class="link">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="people">
        <h1>Maria</h1>
        <img src="https://imgur.com/a/Ejh9X" alt="p3">
        <p>Gay one the what walk then she. Demesne mention promise you justice arrived way. Or increasing to in especially inquietude companions acceptance admiration. Outweigh it families distance wandered ye an. Mr unsatiable at literature connection favourable. We neglected mr perfectly continual dependent. </p>
        <div class="link">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  background: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

.people {
   width: 30.333%;
   background: white;
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   margin: 2px 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: center;
}
.people img {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I'm trying to create a blog of people where their photo,description and link to their social network will be available. I've created a div(container) then another div(people) where their whole profile will be available. To conclude, there will be some people's profile in a div(parent) staying side by side with a little gap.
I'm using float so that each profile stays side by side but after using float the whole container div collapses expect the h1 element in container div. so what should I do so that every item should stay side by side maintaining equal width and height in their parent div.

here's my codepen link - https://codepen.io/buzz_lightyear/pen/aVPQvq

Comment: Seeing as you didn't get an alternative to "flex" like I used in my answer and if it helped your problem, I hope you don't mind marking it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this perhaps? If not, could you add a screenshot as to what you're referring to.

Using a flexbox or CSS Grid helps to manage a grid based layout for elements to have same attributes in a common parent container as shown below. The code below has been modified by adding a parent container called `peoples` which has the `display:flex property` to the child container `people` to have the property of `flex:1` which is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0` which can shrink and grow as the browser is resized and maintains equal attributes on the child elements.

- You can make the profiles container `peoples` to not occupy the entire width of the screen by setting an absolute width (px,em,etc) or relative width(%,vw) and align it according to your needs.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  
}
.peoples{
display: flex;
}

.people {
  width: 30.333%;
  background: white;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  flex:1;
}

.people img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Our Peoples</h1>
    <div class="peoples">
    <div class="people">
      <h1>John</h1>
      <img src="http://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~person/_4170854.jpg" alt="p1">
      <p>Months on ye at by esteem desire warmth former. Sure that that way gave any fond now. His boy middleton sir nor engrossed affection excellent. Dissimilar compliment cultivated preference eat sufficient may. Well next door soon we mr he four. Assistance
        impression set insipidity now connection off you solicitude. Under as seems we me stuff those style at. Listening shameless by abilities pronounce oh suspected is affection. Next it draw in draw much bred. </p>
      <div class="link">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="people">
      <h1>Jonathan</h1>
      <img src="https://www.jamsadr.com/images/neutrals/person-donald-900x1080.jpg" alt="p2">
      <p>His followed carriage proposal entrance directly had elegance. Greater for cottage gay parties natural. Remaining he furniture on he discourse suspected perpetual. Power dried her taken place day ought the. Four and our ham west miss. Education
        shameless who middleton agreement how. We in found world chief is at means weeks smile.</p>
      <div class="link">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="people">
      <h1>Maria</h1>
      <img src="https://engineering.unl.edu/images/staff/Kayla_Person-small.jpg" alt="p3">
      <p>Gay one the what walk then she. Demesne mention promise you justice arrived way. Or increasing to in especially inquietude companions acceptance admiration. Outweigh it families distance wandered ye an. Mr unsatiable at literature connection favourable.
        We neglected mr perfectly continual dependent. </p>
      <div class="link">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://bd.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are always alternative of doing things. But why make things complicated when the tools are provided for achieving a specific task it is made for. If this doesn't answer or solve your query as you posted above then I'm all ears.

Comment: But if it did and no one else gives you a more satisfactory answer you need, make sure to mark it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the `table` tag to help you

The `table` tag simply creates a table that you can put anything you want into and can style with css.

We're going to use this idea to layout three table cells next to each other (like in the code pen) in one row
in a row

Each row is created in html by a pair of `<tr>` tags.
Inside this row there are three table cells `<td>` (the three sections for people). The code looks like this:

```
<tr>
   <!--This is a table row-->
</tr>
```

We are going to create only one row (like in the code pen) and put in it three table cells. Each will contain the image of the person and some text about him:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src="profile_picture.png" alt="John Doe">
         <p>Text Here</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="profile_picture.png" alt="John Doe">
         <p>Text Here</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="profile_picture.png" alt="John Doe">
         <p>Text Here</p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You also say you want there to be space between each container. This can be achieved by setting a padding on the `<td>` tags (table section):

```
td{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200p;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```